# Magento 1.9: Получить Up-sell продукт в таблице, а выбрать в соответствии с названием продукты

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Как могу фильтровать, продукты Up-sell / который я установил для кажды продукт /, так что будут отображаться в моей таблице в соответствии с названием продукта? Моя идея состоит в том, чтобы отображать только продукты, начинающиеся с определенного слова, такие как «Декор», остальные продукты не будет отображаются в таблице. Это мой код upsell.phtml:

```
<?php if(count($this->getItemCollection()->getItems())): ?>
<div class="box-collateral box-up-sell">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('') ?></h2>
    <table style=" border:4px solid white;border-right:4px solid green class="mini-products-grid" id="upsell-product-table">
    <?php // $this->setColumnCount(5); // uncomment this line if you want to have another number of columns. also can be changed in layout ?>
    <?php $this->resetItemsIterator() ?>
    <?php for($_i=0;$_i<$this->getRowCount();$_i++): ?>
        <tr style="white";>
        <?php for($_j=0;$_j<$this->getColumnCount();$_j++): ?>
            <?php if($_link=$this->getIterableItem()): ?>
            <td style=" border-top:4px solid white;border-right:4px solid green>
                <a href="<?php echo $_link->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_link->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_link, 'small_image')->resize(250) ?>" width="170" height="170" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_link->getName()) ?>" /></a>
                <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_link->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_link->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_link->getName()) ?></a></h3>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_link, true, '-upsell') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_link) ?>
            </td>
            <?php else: ?>
            <td class="empty">&nbsp;</td>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endfor; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endfor; ?>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('upsell-product-table')</script>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Я думал про Regular Expressions. Извините меня за русского язька. Я из Болгарии! Спасибо!

Comment: Мой ответ не помог Вам?

Answer (score 1):

Последовал твой совет. Я сделал изменения метод public function getItemCollection в директория
https://github.com/gemgento/magento/blob/master/public/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Upsell.php

```
public function getItemCollection()
    {
        $needle = "DECOR";
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%' . $needle . ' %'));
        return $this->_itemCollection;
    }
```

Пробовал и ето код:

```
public function getItemCollection()
    {
        $needle = "DECOR";
        $this->_itemCollection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%' . $needle . ' %'));
        return $this->_itemCollection;
    }
```

Получаю ошибка:
Fatal error: Call to a member function addAttributeToFilter() on null in

Не знаю где делаю ошибку.

Главное, чего я хочу достичь, - это визуализировать продукты, как я упоминал в начале, содержащиеся в названиях «Декор»,после этого я хочу отображать продукты, содержащий в свое названии «Интерьер»,

Можно сделать ето, вашем пути? Спасибо!

Comment: @Siarhey Uchukhlebau

Comment: А какую коллекцию вы используете? Если это не коллекция продуктов (стандартная) то попробуйте заменить `addAttributeToFilter` на `addFieldToFilter` с теме же параметрами. Хотя судя по ошибке у вас просто нет коллекции в `$this->_itemCollection`, по этому попробуйте написать так: `$collection = paret::getItemCollection();` а после уже добавьте фильтр к `$collection` и напишите `return $collection;`

Comment: Я обновли свой ответ, дополнив его методом который долже сработать в вашем случае.

Answer (score 0):

Все немного проще и сложнее одновременно. Вам нет необходимости фильтровать коллекцию вручную, фреймворк может сделать это за вас. Модифицируйте метод `getItemsCollection()` добавив к нему нужный вам фильтр:

1. Для продуктов имя которых начинается с "Декор"

   ```
   $needle = "Декор";
   $collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => $needle . ' %'));
   ```
2. Для продуктов имя которых содержит слово "Декор"

   ```
   $needle = "Декор";
   $collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%' . $needle . ' %'));
   ```

Если у вас возникнут трудности с этим кодом - напишите мне, я постараюсь помочь.

**Обновление:**

Ваш метод долже выглядеть примерно так:

```
public function getItemCollection()
{
    $collection = parent::getItemCollection();
    $needle = "DECOR";
    if (method_exists($collection, 'addAttributeToFilter')) {
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%' . $needle . ' %'));
    } else {
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('name', array('like' => '%' . $needle . ' %'));
    }

    return $collection;
}
```

**Обновление 2:**

Если вы хотите получить коллекцию продуктов содержащих в названии слова "Декор" или "Интерьер" то вам следует добавить фильтр с условием `OR`:

```
$needle1 = "Декор";
$needle2 = "Интерьер";
$collection->addFieldToFilter(
    'name', 
    array(
        array(
            'like' => '%' . $needle1 . ' %'
        ), 
        array(
            'like' => '%' . $needle2 . ' %'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Спасибо, Siarhey

Comment: если можно посмотри мой коментар. Спасибо!

Comment: @Emo я добавил полный метод в свой ответ, попробуйте использовать его

Comment: Спасибо, друг мой! Я попробовал так $product = Mage::registry('product');
        $this->_itemCollection = $product->getUpSellProductCollection()
 ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%Декор%')));?>
  и получилас. Возможно, это неправильно для Magento, но я должен отфильтровать два слова. В таблице должны отображаться продукты, содержащие слова «Декор» и «Интерьер». И поэтому я думаю, что так невозможно фильтровать. Я хочу спросить вас, можно ли фильтровать самая таблица от view-> upsell.phtml. Надеюсь, получить ваш совет. Даю вам upvote.

Comment: @Emo Я обновил свой ответ, и добавил в конце вариант который вам подойдет - это фильтр с условием `OR` (или). Он позволит вам вывести те продукты, в имени которых есть первое или второе ключевое слово. В остальном код остается неизменным - используйте ранее указанный метод.